# Logistic regression with variables of different granularity (in R)

Tags: r, time-series, logistic, modeling

I want to model a logistic regression test with the Data I have. I have weather data as predictors. Some predictors have granularity of every minutes, 15 minutes, 5 minutes and such while one has granularity of one hour only. Would it be possible to perform Logistic Regression with predictors having different granularity?